# I'm trying to put all the same values inside my input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html code:

```
<div class="input_cont">
<Input type="hidden" id="time" name="time">
</div>
<div class="input_cont">
<Input type="hidden" id="time" name="time">
</div>
<div class="input_cont">
<Input type="hidden" id="time" name="time">
</div>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
const getTime = () {

const inpCont = document.querySelectorAll('.input_cont #time');

inpCont.forEach((fields) => { 
fields.querySelector('#time').value = '5:00:00 AM';
});

}

getTime();
```

But I am getting these errors:

- - Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'value' of null.

    - At NodeList that forEach ()
    - At getTime

Please help me, I am still learning and this is for my school project. Thank you.

Comment: Do not use the same `id` for more then one element

Comment: Do not yell your titles please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: @Intervalia Thanks, but if so, how am I going to put or get all the same values into the fields?

Comment: @Taplar Thanks, but if so, how am I going to put or get all the same values into the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrow function was incorrectly formatted and you used the same ID more than once.

```js
function getTime () {
  const inpCont = document.querySelectorAll('.input_cont [name="time"]');
  inpCont.forEach((fields) => { 
    fields.value = '5:00:00 AM';
  });
}

getTime();
```

```html
<div class="input_cont">
<Input type="text" name="time">
</div>
<div class="input_cont">
<Input type="text" name="time">
</div>
<div class="input_cont">
<Input type="text" name="time">
</div>
```

Comment: This, plus the fact that `fields` in the OP's code already points to the `<input>` elements, so the OP's `fields.querySelector('#time').value = '5:00:00 AM';` should be replaced by `fields.value = '5:00:00 AM';` like this answer did.

Comment: @AnisR. Thank you so much sir! I've been working with this error of almost 2 days and now its finally fixed! Thank you, once again. I need to study more. Hehe